# Facebook Meta Tag Image Issue

Tags: html, facebook, meta-tags

[image]

It is not showing my complete image, i want to set my complete image within that section. I have used following code:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="image_url" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="82" />
```

And the output you can see in image

Comment: This may be a caching issue. Try with a different image url. Also, this may come in handy: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: I am using the same and shared image from same tool. It is returning me this result after clicking "Fetch new Scrap Information"

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution after a long effort and googling.
An image should be equal or higher in dimension by "200X200"

Comment: Don’t know why this needed _“long effort and googling”_ – the debug tool should have told you that straight away.

Comment: because they did not mention that its a hard and fast rule, and that any image below this or high to this will effect in this form